# How update model in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

For example I have my custom class with model.

```
class DbWrapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    explicit DbWrapper(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void connect();
    QSqlDatabase db;
    MyModel* myModel;
}
    void DbWrapper::connect()
{
  ///db.open()
  myModel = new MyModel(0,db);
  /// myModel.select() and another
}
```

and main.qml for example:

```
DbWrapper db();
db.connect();

QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("db", &db);
context->setContextProperty("journalModel", db.tableModel);
```

and in QML for TableView model: journalModel it's working. But I have some problem when me need connect to database after. for example from QML event button click.

```
onClicked{
 db.connect()
}
```

But I can't review my model in QTableView, how i can solve it? MyModel this custom class from QSqlRelationTableModel.

Comment: as I see `DbWrapper` has no property `tableModel`.